# How to fork process with fullRunTask in sbt?

Tags: sbt

I'm writing a sbt plugin that start a server from sbt.

```
lazy val kstart = taskKey[Unit]("Start scala kata")
lazy val Backend = config("backend")
Seq(
  fullRunTask(kstart, Backend, "com.scalakata.backend.Boot", "..."),
  fork in kstart := true,
  connectInput in kstart := false
)
```

The problem is that after the server is started, I dont have a sbt prompt.

```
> kstart
[info] Running com.scalakata.backend.Boot _
// no prompt here :(
```

It look like the process did not fork or something.

Comment: I think you're running your server in a separate JVM, the problem you're having is that sbt will wait for the process to exit before letting you type anything else. See the relevant part of code on [GitHub](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/blob/0.13/run/src/main/scala/sbt/Run.scala#L23)

Comment: yep you are right, can you add your comment as answer? exemple from [sbt-revolver](https://github.com/spray/sbt-revolver/blob/v0.7.2/src/main/scala/spray/revolver/AppProcess.scala#L29)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're running your server in a separate JVM, the problem you're having is that sbt will wait for the process to exit before letting you type anything else.

See the relevant part of code on [GitHub](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/blob/0.13/run/src/main/scala/sbt/Run.scala#L23).

```
// fork with Java because Scala introduces an extra class loader (#702)
val process = Fork.java.fork(configLogged, scalaOptions)
def cancel() = {
  log.warn("Run canceled.")
  process.destroy()
  1
}
val exitCode = try process.exitValue() catch { case e: InterruptedException => cancel() }
```

The call `process.exitValue()` will block until the process exists.

I think you'll have to control the process by yourself if you want it to run in the background.