# How to exit a sbt task?

Tags: scala, sbt, task, actor

I run a sbt task. Normal scenario after it finishes, it should stop in the terminal. But the terminal is not waiting for next input meaning : my task keeps running. I assume some called threads were not exited after the task launched them.

**How to exit clean and kill all processes started by the sbt task ?**
I could debug which service was not stopped but it will take a long time to figure out.

More details

In the build.sbt

```
lazy val refreshTranslations = taskKey[Unit]("blabla")
fullRunTask(refreshTranslations, Compile, "tasks.TranslationTask")
```

In the task

```
object TranslationTask {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    // background stuff with ActorSystem() , AhcWSClient()
    Await.result(service.get, 20.seconds)
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: have you tried crtl + d in the terminal

Comment: I know how to exit in the terminal with cmd + C . I'm asking specifically in SBT.

Comment: your task is running an externally defined function? Why not define it and run it as a regular Task?

Comment: Is this related to this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24600377/1553233

Comment: @marios , it seems like. But as 2017, it looks quite deprecated for SBT

Comment: If you had a copy-pastable (best word ever?) example I could reproduce it and give it a shot.

Comment: I put the example code already in my post. But yes , I am running a client   using ActorSystem(). I don't know what's is not shutting down. So I'd like to kill the whole SBT process.

Comment: akka ActorSystem uses non-daemon threads. You need to call [terminate](http://doc.akka.io/japi/akka/2.4/akka/actor/ActorSystem.html#terminate--) on the ActorSystem prior to JVM exit. Within sbt, you probably want this in a [shutdown hook](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#addShutdownHook-java.lang.Thread-).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to exit the `ActorSystem` after the SBT task finishes.

In the build.sbt , start the task in the different thread.

```
lazy val refreshTranslationsFallback = taskKey[Unit]("Refresh the translations file fallback")
fullRunTask(refreshTranslationsFallback, Compile, "tasks.TranslationTask")
fork in refreshTranslationsFallback := true
```

In the task,

```
object TranslationTask {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    // background stuff with ActorSystem() , AhcWSClient()
    ...
    scala.sys.exit() // important
  }
}
```

Special thanks to [SBT stop run without exiting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5137460/sbt-stop-run-without-exiting)